# Is Skyfall preparing the ground to some major change in the franchise?

Tags: plot-explanation, skyfall, james-bond, movie-franchise

In [Skyfall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyfall), they send a hint that there could be some major changes to the Bond franchise, or even possible a final episode.

For instance:

- For the first time 007 appears getting old
- Q is now a different   character, not just another actor
- M dies

Comment: I'd say [Casino Royale](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0381061/) was the _major change_ in the franchise, because it rebooted the series. Bond's character has been reimagined, so it's not really a surprise that _Q_ and _Moneypenny_ have also been reimagined to fit the "new" Bond series.

Comment: Have you even seen the previous two movies? It would be totally different if you had asked this question about *Casino Royale*.

Comment: Yes, but it seems to me somewhat incompatible, those new M and Q, with a physically weakened, sensitive, and even reluctant 007. Don't you think? it's like if he wants but his body doesn't

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Not at all, rather on the contrary.

They rather **reintroduced classic characters, but adapted them** to the new modern rebooted *Bond*, like Q (who is now rather a hacker than an inventor) or Moneypenny (who is much stronger and more self-confident than the languishing little secretary she was before the reboot). In the end Bond is a different character himself (and not just another actor), as introduced no later than *Casino Royale*.

It is true that the modern Bond is much more vulnerable (both physically and emotionally) and the **stories center much more around Bond himself and his development. But those *"major changes"* rather started with *Casino Royale*** and *Skyfall* seems more like a step towards classic *Bond* movies (while still retaining the modernizations of the "Craig-era").

I didn't find any hint that there could be a final episode. Bond [had his difficulties in this movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/8313/49), but **at the end [he's more confident and ready to go on than ever before](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/8052/49)**. And afterall there will never be a final episode. If you cannot continue a storyline in a reasonable way, you just do a reboot (which is especially common nowadays).

What you may experience is, that **the story of the movie centered much more around the internals of MI6 and directly involved major characters in dramatic events**, especially M dying. This indeed somehow new ground may spark the deduction that if M can just die throughout the movie, then why not Bond also? But in fact the final scene somehow shows (and Mrs. Dench may forgive me for saying that) how replaceable M actually is and that **it requires a bit more than his/her death to endanger the further continuation and overall immutability of James Bond's adventures**. It is just that the new Craig-movies have a much closer relation to each other and a higher overall story-consistency, or call it a more dynamic cross-movie development of the story and characters, compared to the rather ground-up start of virtually each of the pre-Craig movies (in fact [Bond's wife and her death is the only major cross-movie story development](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/8278/49) of the pre-Craig era, I think). But this fine-grained development doesn't neccessarily need to imply major changes in the overall franchise (and in *Skyfall* it certainly didn't).

And as said, the emphasis on Bond's own character and development and his physical and emotional weakness are not a novum of *Skyfall* but rather of the modern Craig-*Bond* as a whole, it's just emphasized a bit more in this movie. But neither does it give me the impression of discovering totally new ground compared to the previous movies. It even **promises more traditional directions, even if not dropping all the modernizations**, in the future (personal disclaimer: I like both the "Craigian" modernizations as well as the more "traditional" *Bond*-movies).

And last but not least, I just found [this related article](http://popcornworld.net/2012/11/18/old-dog-new-tricks-skyfall-and-the-reconstruction-of-bond/) which may provide some additional thoughts about *Skyfall* making a statement for retraditionalizing the franchise. Although I for myself wouldn't go that far, it provides some interresting views.

<sub>(As a little addendum regarding the following film, without going too much into details about it as it's only an afterthought to your actual question: While keeping up with the trend of trying to put an overaching storyline over the series, ***Spectre* indeed went into a very traditional classic *Bond* direction**, maybe even forcefully so.)</sub>

Comment: Exactly my feeling after I left the theater..

Comment: Plus aren't the Craig-era movies technically Prequels? Introducing Bond's (Craig) first days/years at 00 status in the MI6 (just with a modern-times twing to them)?

Comment: "especially M dying. This indeed somehow new ground may spark the deduction that if M can just die throughout the movie, then why not Bond also?". Wow. Talk about prophetic!!! This begs for 2022 update!

Comment: @DVK Yet even his death will ultimately (or hopefully) not be more than just a dent in the continuous adventures of James Bond.

Answer (score 7):

For me it was more like going back to the more traditional Bond and away from the "Jason Bourne" like Action Bond:

- M is a male again
- Moneypenny is back, and her office looks exactly like the old ones (Coat hanger, "typewriter", Wooden Door)
- M's office looks more traditional, it is all heavy wood

Comment: Those details you mention in your last two points were also very obvious for me.